# Docker auto reload not working on remote server

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, pycharm

I've setup a Django project that runs in Docker. I want to have my dev environment on a remote server and have it auto reload as I change my files locally. I've set up remote deployment in Pycharm and it works fine. All local changes are reflected on my remote server, I can also see that files get changed inside the Docker container as I've setup a volume in my docker-compose file. However auto reloading is not working, and I cannot figure out why.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    container_name: my_project_ws
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/my_project/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/my_project/mediafiles
      - .:/my_project
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: my_project_db
    restart: always
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - .env

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/my_project/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/my_project/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile? It's not clear if you're using the built-in server or a different one like gunicorn. If you can provide us with more details so we can help you better.

Comment: I do use Gunicorn. My Dockerfile is not that interesting as it just contains some install instructions. I will update the post with my docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Gunicorn with  `--reload` solved the problem.